# deploying perl dancer on apache with a virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, perl, cgi

Forgive my lack of knowledge I'm just learning linux administration here.

A week ago I read this article about setting up [virtual hosts](http://twohlix.com/2011/05/setting-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos/), I then installed and setup `mod_perl` and **my perl [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) application was running well!**

I then tried [perl Dancer](http://perldancer.org), and it seems deployment isn't all to straightforward for a newbie.

I tried to follow this [article on Deployment in CGI environments](http://advent.perldancer.org/2010/10) but I'm probably just missing something pretty basic.

**The Problem** : I configured my server and now if I goto www.myapp.com on chrome I get :

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

- I have `www.myapp.com` pointed to an **Amazon-EC2**  Amazon Linux instance.
- It's running Apache.
- I have this folder : `/srv/www/myapp.com/` and under that I have a `MyApp` folder with the following dir structure (some files removed for brevity):

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x 2   bin
  lrwxrwxrwx 1   index.cgi -> MyApp/public/dispatch.cgi
  drwxr-xr-x 2   lib
  drwxr-xr-x 5   public
  drwxr-xr-x 3   views
  ```
- **[Updated]** I have a `myapp.com.vhost.conf` under `\etc\httpd\sites-enabled\`. I edited it to look like this, based on the dancer [docs on deploying with cgi](https://metacpan.org/module/XSAWYERX/Dancer-1.3110/lib/Dancer/Deployment.pod#Running-as-a-cgi-script-or-fast-cgi-):

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.myapp.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/myapp.com/MyApp/public
   ServerAdmin you@myapp.com

   <Directory "/srv/www/myapp.com/MyApp/public">
      AllowOverride None
      Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
   </Directory>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dispatch.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]

   ErrorLog /srv/www/myappp.com/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/myapp.com/logs/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- My local error log doesn't have any errors for the last week, and access log has nothing but entires for google bot.

**Update 2** : The error log here `/var/log/httpd/error_log` has mutiple lines saying : `failed to resolve handler MyApp`. Any ideas?

What am I missing here?

Is the virtual host setup NOT for running cgi applications? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was unfortunate and simple.

Under `\etc\sites-enabled` I have a `MyApp.conf.backup`. I assumed after a rename it wouldn't have gotten picked up, but because it was in that directory and the conf file had a entry calling `ModPerl`.

This is why I kept getting : `failed to resolve handler MyApp.`

I moved the file out and everything was up and running :)